# Context.Consumer cannot get value from Provider

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use ContextAPI to share and update the state of a Sidebar. However, I cannot get the context value from the Provider.
Here are my codes:

```
// sidebar-context.js

import React from 'react'

export const SidebarStateContext = React.createContext({
  isOpen: 'true',
  toggleSidebar: () => {},
})
```

// gatsby-browser.js
// I'm using Gatsby so there is no App.js. I use the `wrapRootElement` to wrap the Provider around the app.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { SidebarStateContext } from "./src/context/sidebar-context"

export default class wrapRootElement extends Component {
  toggleSidebarNow = () => {
    console.log("PLEASE BE OK")
  }

  state = {
    isOpen: false,
    toggleSidebar: this.toggleSidebarNow,
  }

  render(element) {
    return (
      <SidebarStateContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {element}
      </SidebarStateContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

// Header.js

```
import Button from "../atoms/Button"
import { SidebarStateContext } from "../../context/sidebar-context"

class Header extends Component {
  render(siteTitle) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <StyledHeader>
          <Space height={24} />
          <SpaceWrapper>
            <SidebarStateContext.Consumer>
              {/* {context => <img src={MenuImage} />} */}
              {({ isOpen, toggleSidebar }) => (
                <Button onClick={toggleSidebar}>{isOpen.toString()}</Button>
              )}
            </SidebarStateContext.Consumer>
            <Link
              to="/"
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <img src={LogoImage} />
            </Link>
            <img src={SearchImage} />
          </SpaceWrapper>
          <Space height={24} />
        </StyledHeader>
        <Divider onDark={true} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

The SidebarStateContext.Consumer just provide the default value from the context file. Can anyone help me spot the error?

Comment: What is the arguments in `render` method? Is it possible in react? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

Comment: where are you changing the state value? it looks like you're just assigning a default state and never changing, hence the values in the consumer are always the same?

Comment: That you don't get provider value from wrapRootElement means it doesn't work as you expect. I don't use Gatsby but shouldn't https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement be a function? You may still need separate App component if you want a root be stateful.

Comment: @iofjuupasli I tried to convert a functional component to a class component so I can create the state. Might be I was wrong to add the argument to the render method. Originally, it's like this: `export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (  <ThemeProvider>{element}</ThemeProvider>)`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu This is just for testing so I set the default value it the context file as `isOpen: true` and set it in the state `isOpen:false`. The Consumer just accept the default value as true => The state in Provider does not work.

Comment: @estus: This is something that I suspected. I tried to convert that to a class to use its state. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe this example helps a bit - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context it "switches" an object instead of a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement) states, `wrapRootElement` is not a component but a function with different signature. If component class is provided instead, it's just called as regular function and not instantiated with React renderer.

In case there should be stateful component, it likely should be defined separately from wrapper function:

```
export default function wrapRootElement({ element }) {
  return <App>{element}</App>;
}

export class App extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <SidebarStateContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </SidebarStateContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```